# From where System.EventArgs get its values?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have this action function for a button:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System.Object  sender, System.EventArgs  e) 
{}
```

I am wondering about who will assign for `e` & `sender` their values?

Comment: Most likely, sender will be the button itself. The button class will set the sender and event args when the click event is raised.

Comment: The for components like the button you can say the framework itself does it. If you really want to understand you'd have to try writing custom components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that raises the event must set the sender and event args. For example, if the button in question is a Winforms element, then the values would be set by the System.Windows.Forms code, and you should be able to find the details for it in the MSDN documentation.

Generally, by convention, the sender will be the object instance that has raised the event. The event args will contain any other information that is relevant to the event.